# Restrict paperclip for fixed dimensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can restrict/ validate paperclip for uploading image with fixed dimentions.

I want to upload image with a fixed dimensions else it should show an error displaying that the size is not proper and upload it with fixed size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the size of the image, you can do in your model:

```
def image_valid?
   g = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(photo.to_file(:original))

   g.width < 500 && g.height < 700 #change these numbers
```

(Assuming you have a `has_attached_file :photo` in your model).